# I have a Chinese Smart Watch a MicroTek DZ09 and trying to get it to sync

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wear-os

I have a DZ09, and on my Android Tablet, Nexus 7 (2013), I have just the MicroTek SmartWatch apk.   The issue I am having is when the watch is connected to my tablet, all I get on my watch is a screen that says "Internet Speed Meter" and some information about the SSID I am connected to.   Is this normal, how do I get it so I can use the watch while it is connected?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general hardware tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  I did manage to find the issue, it was/is the notifications from my network meter APK.  Once I told the notifier to ignore this app the issue went away.